# What are derived names?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Q)The **derived** name of (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>C is

A)Tetramethylmethane

B)2,2-Dimethylpropane

C)Neopentane

D)None of these

The answer was A.

What is a derived name?Never heard of it in any book.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are (were) three main nomenclature systems used for naming organic compounds:

- **Common Name (or trivial name)**. Under this convention this molecule is neopentane. For alkanes, this naming system is based on the positioning of methyl substituents, and gives rise to the iso-, sec-, neo- namiong prefixes.
- **Derived Name**. Who uses this method these days???? This system identifies the central carbon atom which has the most carbon groups attached, and then names the groups as a prefix, and ends the name with 'methane'. The formula are often written with the central carbon unit in square brackets. You may still see derived names on MSDS/SDS under the 'Other Names' section. Under this system this molecule is tetramethylmethane. I can think of more important things to teach you in class if this is what you are learning.
- **IUPAC Name**
  This is the accepted naming convention in use today, which allows for retained names, which usually have their origins in the trivial naming system. Its naming system is based on a systematic framework and is used universally. In older texts (pre 1970s), it was known as the Geneva system or congress. Under this convention, this molecule is 2,2-dimethylpropane.

I can't even find any decent references for you at this point, but will update if I find some.

Comment: Derived names were not taught but it appeared on this test from nowhere and I marked the IUPAC name :P