# Why derived name of nomenclature is used for Alkanes and alcohols only?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

My chemistry textbook says derived system of nomenclature of organic compounds is only limited to alkanes and alcohols!

What is the reason behind it? Is it chemical or like a ritualistic/cultural?

Comment: Could you cite that textbook, and, for the good of everyone else not having that arcane folio, explain what "derived system on nomenclature" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derived system is really, really old. Even my textbook from the 20th century has IUPAC naming. My recommendation would be to just find IUPAC naming online, or just get a new textbook. 
I can't seem to find much on the derived system, but here's another question about it; [LINK](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/what-are-derived-names?rq=1)
I tried searching about, and there really isn't much about it. I don't see why you'd want to learn about it though, as history of nomenclature isn't very useful or interesting. Besides, if you try to use the derived system, no one else is going to know what compound you're describing.

Comment: Bangladeshi textbooks have this system included in the context. I was just interested to know why this system was used for alkanes and alcohols only.